# deployment to google app engine php app

Tags: php, google-app-engine

i didn't succeed to deploy an app to google app engine here is the problem:
I use the google app engine launcher then click on deploy so i got that messages:

> If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
>   application with the command-line parameter
>
> --noauth_local_webserver

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: the appspot.com doesn't apply latest code

Comment: Did you get prompted for authorization in your browser as part of the OAuth2 authentication flow?

Answer (score 0):

Solved I deleted all data browser it comming from oauth key expired